# How to avoid a "You must enter a value" error message in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I'm having issues avoiding a "You must enter a value in the __ field" error message in Access 2016. I have three tables, Tasks, Users, and TaskAssignments, and a split form that looks like:

```
User    Task    Assigned?

User1   Task1   True
User1   Task2   False
User1   Task3   True
User2   Task1   False
User2   Task2   False
User2   Task3   True
User3   Task1   True
User3   Task2   True
User3   Task3   True
```

Each task can have multiple users assigned to it, and each user is assigned to multiple tasks. I want my form to display every possible value, then use a checkbox, so that I can click and add a user to that task. The TaskAssignments table has a primary key and a unique constraint on both TaskID and UserID.

The recordsource for my form is a query:

```
select x.UserName, x.TaskName, ta.is_assigned
from (select * from Tasks, Users) x
left join TaskAssignments ta on (ta.TaskID = x.TaskID and ta.UserID = x.UserID)
```

I have an on click event that checks if a record exists in TaskAssignments and either updates or inserts into TaskAssignments. When I debug.print and manually run my queries, they both do what's expected. When I manually insert a record into my TaskAssignments table, my form behaves how I expect. When I need to insert a new record, however, I receive a message stating that I must enter a TaskID in TaskAssignments.

I've tried requerying the form, but I still receive the error message. Why can't it find the record that I just inserted?

Help please?!? Do I need to drastically rethink my approach here?

Here's the VBA:

```
Private Sub is_assigned_Click()

Dim CurrentUser, AssignmentQuery As String, SelectedUserID, SelectedTaskID As Integer
Dim ShouldInsert, IsAssigned As Boolean

CurrentUser = Environ$("Username")
SelectedUserID = Me.UserID
SelectedTaskID = Me.TaskID
IsAssigned = Me.is_assigned

Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "select UserID, taskID from TaskAssignments where UserID=" & SelectedUserID & " and taskID =" & SelectedTaskID & ";"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.EOF = True Then
    ShouldInsert = True
    Else: ShouldInsert = False
End If

If ShouldInsert = True Then
    AssignmentQuery = "insert into TaskAssignments (UserID, taskID, DateAssignmentUpdated, AssignmentUpdatedBy, is_assigned) values " _
    & vbCrLf & "(" & SelectedUserID & "," & SelectedTaskID & ",#" & Now & "#,'" & CurrentUser & "'," & IsAssigned & ");"

ElseIf ShouldInsert = False Then
    AssignmentQuery = "update TaskAssignments set UserID=" & SelectedUserID & ", DateAssignmentUpdated=#" & Now & "#, AssignmentUpdatedBy='" & CurrentUser & "',is_assigned=" & IsAssigned _
    & vbCrLf & " where taskID = " & SelectedTaskID & " And UserID = " & SelectedUserID & ";"
End If

MsgBox AssignmentQuery
db.Execute (AssignmentQuery)

Forms("Task Assignments").Requery

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Edit** - here are the queries produced:

**Insert**

```sql
insert into TaskAssignments 
(UserID, TaskID, DateAssignmentUpdated, AssignmentUpdatedBy, is_assigned) 
values (301,4,Now(),'mylogin',True);
```

**Update**

```sql
update TaskAssignments 
set UserID=270, DateAssignmentUpdated=Now(), AssignmentUpdatedBy='mylogin', is_assigned=False
where TaskID = 1 And UserID = 270;
```

And a constraint on my TaskAssignments table. Both TaskID and UserID are set as required in my table design (which was my whole goal - I was hoping to avoid adding records to TaskAssignments until the user has actually been assigned to a task).

```sql
alter table TaskAssignments add constraint TaskAssignmentsConstraint unique (TaskID, UserID);
```

Comment: What comes back if you check dB.RecordsAffected right after dB.execute.

Comment: Where do you receive the error message? What line? Does the data get inserted? Does the SQL match your manual sql effort?

Comment: Are you getting this message because you have table level properties; `required: yes` and `allow zero length: No`?

Comment: I edited the description to include the AssignmentQuery values and a constraint on the table. When I create a query, they both do what's expected. For the insert, when I click on another row, I get the error message, even though the record was actually inserted into my table. I have to hit escape to move to another record, but my changes are preserved. If I put me.requery or me.dirty = false into my code, I get the error at that line.
For the update, I get the "Write Conflict" error message, but when I save my changes it behaves as expected.

Comment: The insert/update sql looks valid. Try `db.Execute AssignmentQuery, dbFailOnError` to see if it throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of wrong datatypes, each `Dim` needs its own datatype!

```
Dim CurrentUser As String, AssignmentQuery As String
Dim SelectedUserID As Long, SelectedTaskID As Long  ' don't use 16-bit Integer for ID columns
Dim ShouldInsert As Boolean, IsAssigned As Boolean
```

---

To avoid troubles with date/time formatting: the database engine knows `Now()`, so you can directly use this in the Insert SQL:

```
AssignmentQuery = "insert into TaskAssignments (UserID, taskID, DateAssignmentUpdated, AssignmentUpdatedBy, is_assigned) values " _
& vbCrLf & "(" & SelectedUserID & "," & SelectedTaskID & ", Now(), '" & CurrentUser & "'," & IsAssigned & ");"
```

If it still doesn't work, use `Debug.Print AssignmentQuery` instead of `MsgBox` and add the actual SQL to your question (Ctrl+G shows the output).

---

**Edit**

Re-reading the question and comment, I think the problem is:

You are editing a bound form, and are updating/inserting in the same table the form is based on. That's where the Write conflict on Update comes from, the other error is probably because the bound form is trying to insert a record when you click `is_assigned`, but can't.

So yes, you need to rethink your approach, at least partially.

One solution is to insert the recordsource into a temp table, and base your form on that. Then the rest of the code will probably work.

It may be over-complicating things, though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've taken that into account and updated the description.

Comment: A temp table worked great, I added "select ... into" for my recordsource query, then used my temp table as the form's recordsource.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem trying to update a field that use to be a primary field in my table. When I altered what was considered the primary field I assume access would automatically stop enforcing is not null, but for some reason it didn't.

I fixed it by deleting the field, saving the table recreating the field and saving the table and the problem went away. Of course this wouldn't be an ideal solution if you have data in that table you don't want to lose so you might want to try backing it up first, before you give the solution a try, then reinserting the values.